# Ring Theory problem involving zero-divisors.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I\not = (0)$ be an ideal without non-zero divisors in a ring $R.$ If there exists non-zero $a\in I$ and $r\in R$ such that $ra=0$ then $rI= Ir=(0).$

My Attempt: If $r=0$ then $rI=Ir=(0)$ and we have nothing to prove. If $r\not =0$ then $ra=0$ means that $a$ and $r$ are zero-divisors. So now we want to show that $$rx=0$$ for all $x\in I.$  After this I am not sure what to do. Any hints will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 'without zero divisors'? I never heard of non-zero divisors.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: How is a non-zero divisor defined?

Comment: Wikipedia states that ' an element which is not a zero-divisor, is called a non-zero divisor'. Hence $ra = 0$ with $r \neq 0$ implies that $a$ is a zero divisor or $a$ is zero, both contradictions to the assumptions...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor

Comment: @PeterMelech The book does not give a definition for this.

Comment: @Student $a$ can be a zero divisor right? Because the ideal consists of elements that are not zero-divisors?

Comment: Stupid mistake of my part, got totally confused with the non-zero divisor thing :p

Comment: if a non-zero-divisor is an element that is not a zero divisor an ideal without non-zero-divisors consists of zero-divisors and zero

Comment: If I understand the definitions correctly, I do not believe the statement to be true:

Consider the ring $k[x,y,s,t]/(xy, st)$.
In this ring the ideal $I=(x,s)$ consists only of zero-divisors (since $a(yt)=0$ for every $a\in I$). So it seems that $I$ has "no non-zero divisors".
However for $a=x$, $r=y$ we clearly have $ra=0$ even though $rI=(sy)\neq 0$.